# Django: How to map urls to views dynamically with or without urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have huge `urls.py` with dozen of lines like:

```
url(r'^do_foo$', views.do_foo),
```

i.e. url exactly match name of function within views.

I don't want to create a dispatcher that takes url as parameter and find the appropriate method for performance reason.

**Q:**

Is there a way to either shorten `urls.py` to one line like

```
url(r'^(.*)$', 'views.\\1'),
```

or get rid of `urls.py` entirely.

Comment: `for performance reason`, have your benchmarked it to back that up?

Comment: Yes, this is totally doable, you can call a view directly from the template without the url. Example `{% url 'myapp.views.viewname' %}`

Comment: @karthikr - not without a matching pattern somewhere in urls.py you can't! I think the OP wants to automate mapping URL patterns to view functions, not avoid giving them `name` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `urlpatterns` variable is just Python, so if you can determine which callables you want to map to URLs you can automate it:

```
import inspect
import views

urlpatterns = [url(r'^%s$' % name, view) for name, view in views.__dict__.items()
               if callable(view) and
               inspect.getargspec(view)[0][0] == 'request']
```

But think carefully before doing so - automatically exposing all your views as URLs can open up parts of your app you didn't intend to make public. The inspect argspec check above is a tiny step towards not accidentally opening up too much, but I wouldn't want to rely on it too deeply.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I'm looking for. And yes, I promise to be carefull ;)

Comment: If this answered your question, you might want to mark it as accepted as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to overload django url dispatcher rather than generate urlpatterns for each request?

Comment: I think you'd still end up looking up callables in a module's `__dict__`, then calling out to the view from a dispatch method similar to the way class-based views dispatch based on the HTTP method. I think the generated urlpatterns would be easier to debug, since in debug mode Django will show you what patterns it checked on a 404 and so on

Answer (score 1):

The $ sign at the end of each URL stands for an exact match at the end

For example,

```
url(r'^do_foo$', views.do_foo)
```

will match only /do_foo whereas

```
url(r'^do_foo', views.do_foo)
```

will match

doo_foo/hello

doo_foo/abcd/bar

You can use this to reduce the size of your urls.py

You can't get rid of urls.py entirely, but can map all urls to the same view function using

You can map all urls to the same view function using

```
url(r'', views.do_foo)
```